# alert message on admin page when any user login using c#?asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, datagrid, sqldatasource

i have an asp.net grid i want to update its datasource from another page i am using sqldatasource1 so that grid sync with database on insert operatioon called on another page and results in updation of grid in another page here is my grid code on server.aspx that should be update on login page insert

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
   OnRowCommand="GridView1_OnRowCommand">
   --------coloumn-------------

 </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [logintbl]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

now the above is datasource

here is login.aspx.cs page method code of insertion

login.aspx

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string SetFileNameU2(List<string> someValues)
    {
    //there update grid datasource of server.aspx

      }
```

Comment: Please try to clarify your question as it hard to understand as it is. Provide results and expected output.

Comment: I am saying that like fb notification similarly i want to update my asp.net grid automaticaaly when data inserted by any body from another page to the table

Comment: look i have a table registration , user come and registered him self . at the same time admin is viewing number of user registered hence number raises the grid to admin automatically updated

Comment: Explain what you have done so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: i think when even a new user registered he want an alert message there @VladimirNul do you  have solution for that its my similar prob

Comment: @VladimirNul when a new user register alert message on admin panel like fb without refreshing recives for that solution needed

Comment: nouman edit was better